# List of two JSON requests

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I do not understand how to do the right thing.
With this query I get a JSON with the file names:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.server.com/my/?callback=?",
    function(data){
        var results = [];
        $.each(data['results'], function(i, result) {
            results.push("<div class='accordion-group span4'><div class='accordion-heading'>Video Frame<blockquote><a href='http://server.com/video/?my=" + result.File + "' target='_blank'><img src='http://jpg.server.com/" + result.File + ".jpg' class='img-polaroid'/></a><p>" + result.ListId + "</p><small>" + result.OwnerId + "</small><small>" + result.updatedAt + "</small>    </blockquote><a class='accordion-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion2' href='#" + result.File + "'>Share video</a></div><div id='" + result.File + "' class='accordion-body collapse'><div class='accordion-inner'><form class='share_file_form'>Set list<input name='nd' id='user_id' type='hidden'><input name='file' value = '" + result.File + "' type='hidden'><div class='list'></div><input type='text' placeholder='New list'><div class='modal-footer'><button class='share_file_submit'>Share video</button></div></form><div id='user_info_result'></div></div></div></div>");
        });
        $('#mytile').html(results.join(""));
    }
);
```

With this query I get a JSON with the tag names:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.server.com/list/?callback=?",
    function(data){
    var results = [];
    $.each(data['results'], function(i, result) {
        results.push("<label class='radio'><input type='radio' name='list' id='" + result.List + "' value='" + result.List + "' checked>" + result.List + "</label>");
    });
    $('.my_list').html(results.join(""));
    }
);
```

In the end, I need to display a list of files. Next to each file should to show a form with a file name and a list of tags:

```
$(document).on('click', '.share_file_form', function() {
    $('.share_file_form').validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://api.server.com/set/",
                timeout: 20000,
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $(".share_file_submit").attr("disabled", true);
                    $(".share_file_submit").html("Send <img src='http://src.server.com/loadr.gif' border='0'/>");
                },
                success: function(msg){
                    console.log("Data Saved: " + msg);
                    $("#share_file_submit").attr('disabled', false);
                    $("#share_file_submit").html("Share video");
                    $("#user_info_result_2").html(msg);
                },
                error: function(msg){
////////////////            $('#user_info_result_2').html("<div class='alert alert-error span3'>Failed from timeout. Please try again later. <span id='timer'></span> sec.</div>");
                }
            });
        }
    });


});
```

All of this works.

The question is how to make sure that each form will work separately?
Now only works the first form. If you press the button on the other forms will still work the first form.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you mean "Now only works the first form"? I don't think anyone can answer these questions without seeing the code behind the forms, including any event handlers that may be there, as well as what you expect to happen and what is actually happening.

Comment: what does the button do? Can you show the handler function for that? The code provided is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is in the way you identify the form on which the user clicked. The following line is the problem:

```
$('.share_file_form').validate({
```

Independent of what you clicked on, you always will get the first form with this selector.

Here is what you need instead:

```
$(document).on('click', '.share_file_form', function(event) {
    $(event.target).validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution works, but you press the button on the form page is reloaded. $(document).on('click', '.share_file_form', function(event) {
    $(event.target).validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://api.server.com/share/",
    timeout: 20000,
    data: $(form).serialize(),
    beforeSend: function() {
   $(".share_file_submit").attr("disabled", true);
    },
    success: function(msg){
    },
    error: function(msg){
    }
   });
  }
 });


});

Answer (score 0):

hmm. I 'think' I know what you want..

how about wrapping the second call in a method, or perhaps both, ala.

```
 function fireJSON(){
    var func1 = function(){
      //your first json code
      func2(); // call your second json code
    }
    var func2 = function(){
          // second json code
    }
     return {
       func1: func1
     }

   }


   fireJSON().func1();
```

Comment: what does this have to do with his forms? The form action is not even known to us yet.

Comment: I'm assuming his action is improper. This way, he only has to change the action. But sure, I could wait for him to get back and supply more information, but I'm just going thru questions I might be of assitance to, and probably won't see this post again. But yeah, I don't know what is wrong with his code, I'm just 'assuming' and perhaps this could help, nothing more.